# Why can't you say " 私は学生をしています?

Tags: grammar, nuances

Was practicing and came across some examples of saying what you are.

> 看護師をしています
>
> 学生です

However, they explained that you cannot say the following:

> 学生をしています

It would have to be gakusei desu. Why is that? they are both nouns correct?

If i were to guess, it would be because if you are a student, it is constantly, where as if you are a nurse, its something you only do a few hours a day for work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because this type of する means "to work as ～", "to play the role of ～".

> #### [する](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/#jn-120514)
>
> ２㋑ある役割を努める。ある地位にあって働く。また、そのことを仕事として生活をささえる。「司会をする」「仲人をする」「料理長をしている」「商売をする」

娘, 子供, 赤ちゃん and so on are not the name of a role/occupation, so you cannot use する with them. 主婦をしている is okay if you think it's your job.

学生をしている is a gray area case and sometimes people say this as a response to "what's your job?", but it's usually safer to avoid it in a plain self-introduction.